# How get a day with a carbon by German in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

How get a day with a carbon by German in Laravel?

Try:

```
 return $item->formatLocalized('%A, %d.%m.%Y %H:%M');
```

Need:

```
Montag, 17.04.2017 10:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put this on bootstrap/app.php

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
```

Answer (score 0):

Today (with Laravel 9) the answer is:

set your desired locale in `config/app.php`
with that use `translatedFormat` instead of `format`.

```php
Carbon::parse($string)->translatedFormat($format)
```